# KSOAP 2.5.8 dependencies compile code

Tags: android, eclipse, ksoap, android-studio-2.1

I recently migrated eclipse project to Android Studio, which result KSOAP ERROR. I FOUND [Android ksoap web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278527/android-ksoap-web-service) I use KSOAP 2.5.8 in Eclipse. So Please help me to solve this. Gone through different keywords in stackOverFlow, But the stack what I am searching is not found. Struggling from 1 hour.  [Android ksoap web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278527/android-ksoap-web-service)

Comment: post your relevant code here?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I solved It just now. I simply added "libs" folder and added jars to that folder. After that Right click on the Jar file I choose Add as Library[2nd option from down]. which solve my problem.